# Replacing dplyr's spread by pivot_wider and gather by pivot_longer

Tags: r, dplyr

In a recent release of dplyr `spread()` and `gather()` have been marked as *lifecycle: retired*. `pivot_wider()` and `pivot_longer()` shall be used.

My issue is that the new functions require more typing and seem to be executing slower. I wonder if I'm doing anything wrong.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("1975-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-10-31"), by = "months")

returndata <- tibble(stock = sort(rep(letters, length(dates))),
                     month = rep(dates, length(letters)),
                     ret   = runif(length(dates) * length(letters)) - 0.5)
```

Previously I'd spread the data as follows:

```
returndata_spread <- returndata %>% 
  spread(stock, ret)
```

With pivot_wider I'd do:

```
returndata_wider <- returndata %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = stock, values_from = ret)
```

The result is exactly the same.

To gather previously:

```
returndata_gather <- returndata_wider %>% 
  gather(stock, ret, -month)
```

Now with pivot_longer:

```
returndata_longer <- returndata_wider %>% 
  pivot_longer(-month, names_to = "stock", values_to = "ret") %>% 
  arrange(stock, month)
```

I measure the execution times and got the following:

```
> t_spread
Time difference of 0.01287794 secs

> t_wider
Time difference of 0.4083362 secs

> t_gather
Time difference of 0.002280474 secs

> t_longer
Time difference of 0.01168776 secs
```

The new functions are considerably slower.

Comment: If speed is important you might consider using also `data.table`. One example: `setDT(returndata);dcast(returndata, month ~ stock)`

Comment: if typing is the issue, use Rstudio - the autofill and 'tab' will allow you to type `pivot_wider` just as quickly as `spread`. I personally find pivot_wider MUCH easier to use and remember than spread and also it seems much more predictable (and reliable) in what it outputs - e.g., it seems to handle apparent 'duplicate' identifiers much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be another instance of [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/775) issue on Github, which is supposed to be fixed in the dev version of `tidyr`. After updating `tidyr` (i.e.`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")`) I get comparable performance on your example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dates <- seq(from = as.Date("1975-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-10-31"), by = "months")

returndata <- tibble(stock = sort(rep(letters, length(dates))),
                     month = rep(dates, length(letters)),
                     ret   = runif(length(dates) * length(letters)) - 0.5)

bench::mark(
  spread = returndata %>% spread(stock, ret),
  pivot_wider = returndata %>% pivot_wider(names_from = stock, values_from = ret)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 spread        8.83ms   9.57ms     100.         0B     6.39
#> 2 pivot_wider  10.96ms  11.37ms      86.1        0B     4.42
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>